# One-liner to create an object with all keys of previous nested object but a subset of keys-value pair from each value

Tags: javascript, object

I have an array of the form:

```js
const obj1 = { 
  key1: {
    a: 'x',
    b: 2
  },
  key2: {
    a: 'y',
    b: 4
  },
  key3: {
    a: 'z',
    b: 3
  }
}
```

I want to create a new object `obj2` of the form:

```js
const obj2 = { 
  key1: 'x',
  key2: 'y',
  key3: 'z',
}
```

I could do it using for...in loop, but I need a one-liner.

```js
const obj2 = {};
for (let key in obj1) {
  obj2[key] = obj1[key].a
}
```

Please tell me how do I create a one-liner for this.

Comment: Your code is simple and easily understandable. Complicated one-liner isn't better code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can map the keys of the object and return objects for each element containing the desired structure. Then you can spread the results into a newly assigned object.

```js
const obj1 = { 
    key1: {
        a: 'x',
        b: 2
    },
    key2: {
        a: 'y',
        b: 4
    },
    key3: {
        a: 'z',
        b: 3
    }
};

console.log(Object.assign(...Object.keys(obj1).map((k) => ({ [k]: obj1[k].a }))));
```

Answer (score 3):

You can take Object.entries and then use `reduce`:

```js
const obj1 = { key1: { a: 'x', b: 2 }, key2: { a: 'y', b: 4 }, key3: { a: 'z', b: 3 }};

const result = Object.entries(obj1).reduce((a,[key, val])=>(a[key]=val.a,a),{});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could map the entries with a destructuring for a new object.

```js
const
    object = { key1: { a: 'x', b: 2 }, key2: { a: 'y', b: 4 }, key3: { a: 'z', b: 3 } },
    result = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(object).map(([k, { a }]) => [k, a]));

console.log(result);
```